# Django Templates and render() - How to access multiple values

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Learning Django and I'm having an issue with accessing 2 different values.

In `views.py` under `def home(request`, I've added a list of 2 dictionary objects and passed it through under `context`. It works perfectly, I'm about to for loop over the dictionary in my `front_page.html` template, but I've also added a simple `if title` variable which only works if I place `{'title': 'Competitive'`} **before** the variable `context`.

```
 from django.shortcuts import render


# Create your views here.

owl = [
    {
        'title': 'Competitive'
    },
    {
        'Team': 'Dynasty',
        'Location': 'Souel Korea',
        'Colors': 'Black & Gold',
    },
    {
        'Team': 'OutLaws',
        'Location': 'Houston',
        'Colors': 'Green & Black',
    }
]


def home(request):
    context = {
        "owl": owl
    }

    return render(request, 'overwatch_main_app/front_page.html', context, {'title': 'Competitive'})


def second(request):
    return render(request, 'overwatch_main_app/about.html', {'title': 'Boom'})
```

I've even tried `comp = {'title': 'Competitive'}`, and placing `comp` into the `render()`. It only works when I place `comp`, or `{'title': 'Competitive'}`before `content` and then `content` doesn't work.

```
return render(request, 'overwatch_main_app/front_page.html', comp, context)

return render(request, 'overwatch_main_app/front_page.html', {'title': Competitive'} , context)
```

How can I pass more than 1 value of dictionaries to my template via `render()`

**front_page.html**

```
{% extends 'overwatch_main_app/base.html'  %}

{% block content %}

    <h1> OverWatch</h1>

    {% for o in owl %}

        <p>{{o.Team}}</p>
        <p>{{o.Location}}</p>
        <p>{{o.Colors}}</p>

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    {% if title %}
        <title>OverWatch {{title}}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title> OverWatch </title>
    {% endif %}

</head>
<body>

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only have one context dict, but a dictionary can have as many key/values as you like.

```
context = {
    "owl": owl,
    "title": "Competitive"
 }
return render(request, 'overwatch_main_app/front_page.html', context)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you, as a sign to future searchers.

Comment: Tried but rep is only at 14.